# Changing values in multiple column given one condition (preferably in dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for an easy way to change several values for the same person. Preferably with dplyr or any other package from tidyverse.

Here my example:

```
df <- data.frame(personid = 1:3, class = c("class1", "class3", "class3"), classlevel = c(1, 11, 3), education = c("BA", "Msc", "BA"))
df
```

My dataset contains an entry with several mistakes. Person #2 should be part of class 1, at classlevel 1 und his education is BA, not MSc. I use mutate with case_when a lot, but in my case I don't want to change one variable with multiple condition, I have one condition and want to change multiple values in other variables based on this condition.

Basically, I'm looking for an shorter code which replaces this:

```
df$class[df$personid == 2] <- "class1"
df$classlevel[df$personid == 2] <- 1
df$education[df$personid == 2] <- "BA"
df
```

or this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df |> 
   mutate(class = case_when(personid == 2 ~ "class1", TRUE ~ class)) |> 
   mutate(classlevel = case_when(personid == 2 ~ 1, TRUE ~ as.numeric(classlevel))) |> 
   mutate(education = case_when(personid == 2 ~ "BA", TRUE ~ education))
df
```

In my original data, there are several dozend cases like this, and I find it a bit tedious to use three lines of code for each person. Is there a shorter way?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create a data frame of the values to be updated and use `rows_update()`.  Note that this assumes the rows are uniquely identified.

```
library(dplyr)

df_update <- tribble(
  ~personid, ~class, ~classlevel, ~education,
  1,   "class1", 1, "BA"
  )  

df %>%
  rows_update(df_update, by = "personid")

  personid  class classlevel education
1        1 class1          1        BA
2        2 class1          1        BA
3        3 class3          3        BA
```

Comment: Awsome, like this it's more clear what was being changed. Thanks a lot for your fast answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I need a little bit more information to try to answer your question., but I'll try anyway.

If you want to change the value of some columns based on a unique condition *across all the rows* I recommend doing this (I created new columns `col_name1` so you can see the original and ouput):

```
df <- df %>% mutate(class1 = case_when(class != "class1" ~ "class1", TRUE ~ class), 
                    classlevel1 = case_when( classlevel != 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ as.numeric(classlevel)),
                    education1 = case_when( education != "BA" ~ "BA", TRUE ~ education))
```

If that was your problem, then you are probably not familiar with the concept of **vectorization**. Briefly, a vectorized function runs for all the rows or elements in your vector, without you needing to specify that. There are a lof of examples and tutorial on the web if you search "vectorization in R" or something similar.

Otherwise, if your condition changes for each single id (or row) in your data, then the problem is more complicated.

Let me know if that helps and, if it doesn't, consider providing more information in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My csv includes 22 variables and over 80'000 observations. Each one has an unique identificator. Sometimes I need to correct certain values, as they were inserted with the wrong code/number.

Comment: Full answer: Thank you for your answer. My csv includes 22 variables and over 80'000 observations. Each one has an unique identificator. Sometimes I need to correct certain values, as they were inserted with the wrong code/number. Sometimes it's only one value I have to correct, for this base R is fine. But sometimes I have to replace several specific values in specific  cells as they are connected. For example, a student is alone in a class. I want to add this person to another existing class and add the level and education this class is getting. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: Gotcha, I guess @Ritchie answer solves your problem neatly then :)